# Как заполнить список длиной N числами от 1 до N?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Как можно сделать, что бы список заполнялся от 1 до N числа. К примеру, я ввожу число 10, и нужно, чтобы ответ вывелся так 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для формирования списка нужного размера можно использовать функцию `range`

```
N = int(input("Введите размер списка: "))
spam = list(range(1, N+1))
print(spam)

> Введите размер списка: 10
> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

В `python-2.x` достаточно следующего кода:

```
N = 3
print range(1, N + 1)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

или текстом:

```
N = 3
print " ".join(map(str, range(1, N + 1)))
# 1 2 3
```

В `python-3.x` схема работы `range` изменена, напрямую возвращает класс, поэтому чтобы вывести список принудительно проводим через `list`:

```
print(list(range(1, N+1)))
# [1, 2, 3]

print(" ".join(map(str, range(1, N+1))))
# 1 2 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Def N = int(input("5: ")) spam = list(range(1, N+1)) print(spam) > 5: 10 > [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
N = 3 print range(1, N + 1) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: а это точно python?